# How to define a function 'server.remove' identical to 'server.revert'

Tags: filepond

How to define a function 'server.remove' (removing local files) identical to 'server.revert'.

'server.revert' send 'DELETE' request to '/api' with filename in request body.

I do not quite understand how the function should be organized, try something like that, but it does not work:

```
mounted() { 
          this.server = {
            url: '/api',
            remove: (source, load, error, revert) => {
                revert(source);
                error('oh my goodness');
                load();
            },
            headers: { 
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token,
              },
          };
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#remove-1) for the function signature, so something like this:

```js
this.server = {
  remove: (source, load, error) => {

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('DELETE', 'url-to-api/' + source);

    request.onload = function () {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
        load(request.responseText);
      } else {
        error('oh no');
      }
    };

    request.send();
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  
There is no way to make a solution like that?  
`
mounted() {  
          this.server = {  
            remove: (source, load, error, revert) => {  
                revert(source);  
            },  
          };  
    },  
`